# How to fetch last inserted record in mysql using nifi

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi, last-insert-id

am trying to insert a record in mysql database and fetch the last inserted record on success of insertion using nifi. below is flow structure am trying.

```
convertJsontomysql -> putSQL(insert record) -> executeSQL (query to fetch last inserted record)
```

but it throws an error, I don't know how to achieve this somebody please help.

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the structure of the table?

Comment: Hi @BenYaakobi, it's a simple table with basic fields, I can successfully insert the record on success trying to fetch the last inserted record using executeSQL but it throws an error, if I run the same query individually in executeSQL It works perfectly.

Comment: What are basic fields? Is there an auto increment ID field? What is the query you're trying to perform?

Comment: @BenYaakobi Basic fields are id, name, created_dt,modified_dt yes 'ID' is auto increment field,

`SELECT 'id','name' FROM  table1 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1);`

the above query I tried to run in executeSQL processor

Comment: I've added my answer :)

Comment: @BenYaakobi but I can run the query I've provided in executeSQL processor standalone, if I connect it for putSQL to executeSQL at that time only am facing the problem

Comment: Could you provide the ExecuteSQL configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try running query `SELECT max(id), name FROM table1` instead.
If you still want to use wrapper for the name, use ` instead of '(backtick instead of an apostrophe).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this will work? in between new records might have already been inserted into the table. So you might not get the id of the record in question.

Maybe a better solution would be to end the flow with the PutSQL and Have a second one picking up the data? You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745887/nifi-querydatabasetable-processor-how-to-query-rows-which-is-modified) to get some ideas.